# How to use .split, enumerate and lists to find positions of a word in a sentence

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been asked to find the position(s) of an input word from an input sentence and I am having trouble figuring out how to use enumerate, .split and lists together. This is what I have so far:

```
sntc=str(input("Please input a sentence with no punctuation."))
wrd=str(input("Please input a word from that sentence."))
words=sntc.split
list(enumerate(sntc))
for x in y in enumerate:
    if x==(wrd):
        print ("The chosen word is in postion(s):",x+1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to convert input to a `str`. It's already a string.

`words` isn't what you think it is. All that is is a reference to the `split` method. You never actually *call* the method `split`.

e.g. -

```
>>> a_string = "Look a  string"
>>> print(a_string.split)
>>> <built-in method split of str object at (memory address)>
```

Whereas *calling* split, we have:

```
>>> print(a_string.split())
>>> ['Look', 'a', 'string']
```

It's unclear what exactly you're trying to achieve with enumerate and everything below `words = sntc.split`. I think you actually want to split `sntc` enumerate over it and check if the given `wrd` matches an item in this split list.

There's another problem, enumerate returns the index in the iterable and the item in the iterable, the index (position) here will just be the position in this list (words) + 1.

Not the actual position *in the sentence*.

e.g. -

```
>>> sntc = input("Please input a sentence with no punctuation: ")
Please input a sentence with no punctuation: Look a sentence
>>> wrd = input("Please input a word from that sentence: ")
Please input a word from that sentence: a
>>> words = sntc.split()
```

Words = `['Look', 'a', 'sentence']`. Position of 'a' is 1 here.

```
>>> for i, word in enumerate(words):
...      if word == wrd:
...          print("Chosen word is in position %d" % (i + 1))
...
Chosen word is in position 2 #Position of 'a' + 1
```

What you actually want is:

```
for word in words:
    if word == wrd:
        print("Position is %d" % sntc.index(word))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution you're looking for - simple and efficient:

```
sntc = input("Please input a sentence with no punctuation. ")
wrd = input("Please input a word from that sentence. ")
words = sntc.split()
print(words.index(wrd) + 1)
```

Using enumerate and lists:

```
sntc = input("Please input a sentence with no punctuation. ")
wrd = input("Please input a word from that sentence. ")
words = sntc.split()
e = list(enumerate(sntc))
for ind, word1 in e:
    if word1 == wrd:
        print("The chosen word is in postion(s):", ind+1)
```

Your code doesn't work for a few reasons:

1) If you want to assign a return value of a function to a variable, call the function to get that return value and not the function itself:

```
>>> words = sntc.split
>>> words                  # the variable words now contains a function
<built-in method split of str object at 0x0243F4D0>
>>> words = sntc.split()
>>> words                  # and now a list that you want
['text', 'text', 'text']
```

2) You can't iterate over `enumerate`, as it's a function and not an iterable
You didn't assign the `list(enumerate(sntc))` to any variable, and I'm pretty sure you meant to iterate over that:

```
e = list(enumerate(sntc)) # now you can iterate over e
for ind, word in e:
    print(ind, word)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want the position of an element in a list use listname.index()

```
a = ["hello", "world"]
a.index("hello")
returns 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The following approach helps you to use .split, enumerate and lists to find positions of a word in a sentence.

```
sentence = 'I like movie'       # given sentence
sentence = sentence.split()     # spliting sentence to split
wrd = 'like'                    # a given word to find position in the sentence
[i for i, w in enumerate(sentence) if w==wrd]
```